# Can I retrieve Apple TV purchases made on my spouse's account?

Tags: itunes-store

Can I retrieve Apple TV purchases made on my wife's iTunes-store account?

Answer (score 1):

Using Family Sharing in iOS8; otherwise only by signing in to her account.

[Sharing purchased content with Family Sharing](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT201085?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)